# '.class' expected error when calling a method with an array

Tags: java

I've bought three books so far and watched several videos and I still am unclear why this doesn't compile.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to read in a file of credit card numbers and check that against the user entered number in my main.  Here is my class followed by my main:
(Thanks for any assistance)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Validator1
    {
        int[] valid;    

    public Validator1()throws IOException
    {   

    }

    public Validator1(String fileName)throws IOException
    {   
        int beginning = 0;
        int place = 0;
        int size = 0;

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(file);

        while(inputFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            size++;
            inputFile2.nextInt();
        }


        while(inputFile2.hasNextInt() && place < valid.length)
        {
            valid[place] = inputFile2.nextInt();
            place++;
        }

    }

    public void sort(int[]valid)
    {
        valid = new int[valid.length];
        for(int start = 0; start < valid.length; start++)
        {
            int lowestValue = valid[start];
            int lowestIndex = start;
            for(int i = start + 1; i < valid.length; i++)
            {
                if(valid[i] < lowestValue)
                {
                lowestValue = valid[i];
                lowestIndex = i;
                }
            }
            int temp = valid[start];
            valid[start] = valid[lowestIndex];
            valid[lowestIndex] = temp;
        } 
    }

    public boolean isValid(int[] valid, int number)
    {
        int low =0;
        int high = valid.length-1;
        while(high >= low)
        {
            int middle = (high + low)/2;
            if(valid[middle] == number)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (valid[middle] < number)
            {
                low = middle +1;
            }
            if(valid[middle] > number)
            {
                high = middle-1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}




import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ChargeIt1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int accountNumber;
        int[] valid = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
        String fileName1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        String fileName = fileName1 + ".txt";

        File file = new File(fileName);

        while(!file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("the file does not exist");
            System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
            fileName1 = keyboard.nextLine();
            fileName = fileName1 + ".txt";
            file = new File(fileName);

        }
        System.out.println("Enter your charge account number: ");
        accountNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Validator1 val = new Validator1(fileName);
        try
        {
            Validator1 val = new Validator1(fileName);
            if(val.isValid(valid, accountNumber))
                System.out.println("That is a valid account number.");
            else
                System.out.println("That is an INVALID account number.");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your constructor deals with an uninitialized array.

Comment: what does the compiler say ? do you have some compiler output ?

Comment: Do not "fix" the question with the solutions provided by the answers.  It renders the answers meaningless.  The real goal of StackOverflow is to gather useful Questions and Answers (to the Questions asked) ...

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
int[] valid = 0;
```

0 isn't an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `ChargeIt1` class, here:

```
if(val.isValid(valid[], accountNumber))
    System.out.println("That is a valid account number.");
else
    System.out.println("That is an INVALID account number.");
```

You first argument to the `val.idValid` method (`valid[]`) is illegal syntax. Replace that line with this:

```
if(val.isValid(valid, accountNumber))
```

And that should take care of your compiler error. Quick note, this is something that would have been quickly highlighted by an IDE, which I highly recommend using, ***especially*** when just starting on programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous errors in your code.

To address just this line:

```
int[] valid = 0;  // does not compile
```

You have a few options to fix it:

Arrays are fixed in length, and to initialize an array, you must provide a dimension, for example:

```
int[] valid = new int[10];
```

However, because arrays are fixed, your code could read more input than the array has room for. There's another approach - use Collections, which expand in size automatically as required.